# How to prevent a pointer of base class to point to derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stack, void, void-pointers

I have the following problem that looks like this.

```
class Animal
{
   void* value;
   public:
   Animal() {}
   void* getValue() {return value;} 
}

class IntAnimal : private Animal
{
  public:
  IntAnimal() {}
  int getValue() {return (*(int*)Animal::getValue());}
}
```

Basically the base class return void*, but the derived class return a regular type (int, double, char, etc).

I need to make either:

1. We can do: `Animal* intAnimal = new IntAnimal(); int x = intAnimal->getValue();` I think this is not possible.
2. Prevent others from doing: `Animal* intAnimal = new IntAnimal();`

How do I prevent others from doing (2) ? Thank you.

Edit: yes this is a terrible design and I should use template. But, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: But.. why? Shouldn't the animal be a template? Or... Why does `value` exists in Animal at all if it doesn't represent anything? Why isn't `getValue` just a virtual function = 0 and the value is stored as an int in IntAnimal? In short, what are you trying to represent?

Comment: Yes, Animal should 100% be a template. And this is a terrible design. But to make things unpractically, unrealistically difficult, I am asked by the question to use void* instead of template

Comment: @user3192711 "*asked*": Is that an assignment for school?

Comment: Not an assignment, but just a problem I read. The obvious solution is to use template. But is there anyway to solve this problem without template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing for you to do.

Your current code forbids `new IntAnimal();` for others in the first place, because the constructor is `private`.

Even if you change that, your conditions are still satisfied. Since the `Animal` base is inherited as `private`, it is inaccessible to outside code and the implicit cast ill-formed.

```
Animal* intAnimal = new IntAnimal();
```

will not compile.

Inside the class and `friend`s the base class and constructor are always accessible and there is never an issue with that condition.

---

It is impossible to prevent the implicit cast from `IntAnimal*` to `Animal*` if `Animal` is inherited as `public` by `IntAnimal`.

---

Also note that inheritance being `private` does not prevent code from explicitly casting to `Animal*`. Any outside code can always use a C style cast

```
Animal* intAnimal = (Animal*) new IntAnimal();
```

which here behaves equivalent to the implicit cast, with the difference that it ignores the accessibility of the base class and will succeed independently of whether `Animal` is inherited as `private` or `public`.

Comment: I'm sorry. The things inside IntAnimal  are public. I have edited the post

Comment: @user3192711 It doesn't really change the answer though, as long as the inheritance is `private`.

Comment: Ohhh. I'm so used to doing Base *base = new Derived() that I forgot it's sometimes impossible. Keyword is private inheritance. Thank you